# How can i change the name of a field as a function argument mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB and i want to have the following schema :

```
directory: {
    "file1": "id",
    "directory1":{
        "file1": "..."
        "file2": "..."
        "file3": "..."
        "direcrtory1": {}
   } 
}
```

My question is: how can i select the field name of function $push as an argument for the following function?

```
function createFile(projectId,filename,id){
        return Project.updateOne({projectId:projectId},{$push:{directory:{filename: id}}});
}
```

The code above creates this in the database:

```
"directory": [
    {
        "id": "someID",
        "filename": "something"
    }
```

Now, I don't want the 'filename' be named that way. I want it to be named as the value that was transferred through the function

example: if function gets the following parameters(someID,'something','anotherId
) , in the database i will have 'filename':'anotherId', and the output i want to have is :  'something':'anotherId' . How can I get that?

Any help would be appreciated

Solution :

```
var update = {$set:{}};
update.$set[filename] = id;
Project.updateOne({projectId: projectId},update,{upsert: true});
```

Comment: From your update sample, it looks like you’re using Mongoose as well, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of using a Mongoose Schema is to enforce the shape of the objects in a Mongo collection. It won't persist fields that don't conform to the schema.   If you want each stored object to have different fields like you're describing, you need to either use the MongoClient directly to save a plain JS object, or else define a Mixed type in your schema where you want the variable names to occur.

If you do the latter,note that you have to call `markModified()` before saving to get Mongoose to recognize the change occurred.

Ok, so adding an example for Mongoose. You'd just do what I said.

```
  const DirectorySchema = new Schema({ 
             path: String,
             contents: Mixed 
   });
```

Then the "contents" field can store whatever you want, but you have to call `markModified` before saving a model based on that schema.

Comment: Ok, so I can't have a different field name for each registration in my database?

Comment: Like I said, You can in an embedded document if that embedded document is registered as a Mixed data type, or you can also do it by not using Mongoose.  The database doesn’t care, but Mongoose is there to enforce a schema.

Comment: Can you give me an examples of how could I do that?